# How to use atomic operations with user-space variable in BPF?

Tags: linux-kernel, ebpf, bpf, compare-and-swap, libbpf

I am trying to do a CAS with `__sync_val_compare_and_swap` in my eBPF code. As this operation needs to be atomic I cannot use `bpf_probe_read_user`. With a regular kernel variable `__sync_val_compare_and_swap` works with no issue.

However when using a pointer allocated in the user space, the verifier raises `misaligned access off (0x0; 0xffffffffffffffff)+0+0 size 8`.

Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
#include "vmlinux.h"
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_tracing.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_core_read.h>

__u64 *state_ptr;

char _license[4] SEC("license") = "GPL";

SEC("tp_btf/sched_switch")
int BPF_PROG(sched_switch_btf, bool preempt, struct task_struct *prev, struct task_struct *next)
{
    if (!preempt || state_ptr == NULL)
        return 0;

    bpf_printk("State: %ld", state_ptr);
    __sync_val_compare_and_swap(state_ptr, 0, 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the full verifier log:

```
libbpf: prog 'sched_switch_btf': BPF program load failed: Permission denied
libbpf: prog 'sched_switch_btf': -- BEGIN PROG LOAD LOG --
reg type unsupported for arg#0 function sched_switch_btf#29
0: R1=ctx(off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0
; int BPF_PROG(sched_switch_btf, bool preempt, struct task_struct *prev, struct task_struct *next)
0: (79) r1 = *(u64 *)(r1 +0)          ; R1_w=scalar()
; if (!preempt || state_ptr == NULL)
1: (15) if r1 == 0x0 goto pc+14       ; R1_w=scalar()
2: (18) r1 = 0xffffb4aa86b6e000       ; R1_w=map_value(off=0,ks=4,vs=8,imm=0)
4: (79) r3 = *(u64 *)(r1 +0)          ; R1_w=map_value(off=0,ks=4,vs=8,imm=0) R3_w=scalar()
5: (15) if r3 == 0x0 goto pc+10       ; R3_w=scalar()
; bpf_printk("State: %ld", state_ptr);
6: (18) r1 = 0xffff9b028dc40f10       ; R1_w=map_value(off=0,ks=4,vs=11,imm=0)
8: (b7) r2 = 11                       ; R2_w=11
9: (85) call bpf_trace_printk#6       ; R0=scalar()
; __sync_val_compare_and_swap(state_ptr, 0, 1);
10: (18) r1 = 0xffffb4aa86b6e000      ; R1_w=map_value(off=0,ks=4,vs=8,imm=0)
12: (79) r1 = *(u64 *)(r1 +0)         ; R1_w=scalar()
13: (b7) r2 = 1                       ; R2_w=1
; __sync_val_compare_and_swap(state_ptr, 0, 1);
14: (b7) r0 = 0                       ; R0_w=0
15: (db) r0 = atomic64_cmpxchg((u64 *)(r1 +0), r0, r2)
misaligned access off (0x0; 0xffffffffffffffff)+0+0 size 8
processed 13 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 1 peak_states 1 mark_read 0
-- END PROG LOAD LOG --
```

`state_ptr` is assigned when the bpf code is loaded. I have checked that the address stored in `state_ptr` is equal to the address of my variable.

I am using clang-16 and Linux kernel 6.1.0.

I tried the same code with a kernel variable. This worked
I tried ensuring state_ptr was not null to make the verifier happy. Did not work

Answer (score 0):

What architecture do you use?

Atomic operations will only work on aligned data on `ARM/ARM64`. Align your data in the *user mode application* (or add fill bytes in a struct). The kernel data will be aligned by the compiler settings in the kernel Makefile.

Comment: I am on x86_64. I will try aligning the user space data and report back. Thank you!

Comment: I just noticed you said on `ARM/ARM64` and I am on x86_64 so this wouldn't have worked. Anyway, my data was already padded and aligned.